# PHP Date create from format returning null?

Tags: php, date

I have a string with the value, `25 July 2014 15:01` and I'm trying to turn it into a timestamp.

This is the code that I'm trying to use, although it's not working, any ideas?

```
    $date = date_create_from_format('j F y G:i', $dateString);
    var_dump($date);
```

This is my code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pg2o5piz45g3piw/Screenshot%202014-07-26%2019.03.22.png

And this is the output: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o5jr6ob23crsbf6/Screenshot%202014-07-26%2019.03.20.png

Fixed.

I am using the simple_html_dom module, and I was accidentally using outertext instead of innertext, so I was getting the span html as well!

Comment: Stack Overflow has an awesome markdown editor to post code (as well as inline pictures). There's no need to bother taking screenshots of your code and uploading them to external services—they are also not indexable and cannot be copied and pasted.

Answer (score 2):

`y` (lowercase) denotes a two digit representation of the year - try uppercase *(full year)* instead:

```php
$date = date_create_from_format('j F Y G:i', $dateString);
var_dump($date);
```

Outputs something like:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
      string(19) "2014-07-25 15:01:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
      string(13) "Europe/London"
}
```

You might want to check out the [`Date` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$str = "25 July 2014 15:01";
echo strtotime($str);
```

`strtotime()` will automagically parse almost any string which has datetime information into an Unix timestamp. You can do nifty things like:

```
echo strtotime("+1 day");
echo strtotime("next Thursday");
```

:)

Comment: `echo "new:" . strtotime($dateString);` I added this, although nothing is coming up, nor is there anything in the PHP error log.

Comment: @HarryTorry - what is value of $dateString? Can you paste that?

Comment: See the original comment, I've added images!

Comment: @HarryTorry - when I run this `$str = "25 July 2014 15:01";
echo strtotime($str);` I get `1406293260`. In your code, comment all the rest of the lines and see running just these ones first.

Comment: FYI, `strtotime()` uses the same heuristics that the `DateTime` constructor.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - yup it does.